# How to resolve "control@RowNoteEmpty" error in acumatica framework

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

While adding a new record the application gives the error "control@RowNoteEmpty" but data is getting saved into the database and after saving and refreshing the screen the error is get resolved. Please refer to the screenshot for the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bv7g.png)

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the reason behind this could be the *Files* and *Notes* controls of the grid. So, would suggest and try setting `FilesIndicator="false" NoteIndicator="false"` properties of the corresponding `PXGrid` in the corresponding ASPX page.